# Tags which give the same result

Tags: html

I try to learn HTML5. I learn to use tags.

I observed that the following tags give the same result. What is the difference?

```
    <b>bold</b>
    <i>italics</i>
    <strong>bold</strong>
    <em>italics</em>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 specification defines the semantic difference between Bold and Strong.

The `<b>` tag is for "offset text conventionally styled in bold". If you read deeper into the details you'll see it adds, "without conveying any extra emphasis or importance".

`<strong>` is different. It "represents a span of text with strong importance." There is semantic meaning of importance here. In fact, a  tag within another  tag has even more importance.

Just like `<strong>` and `<b>` we have changes to  and `<i>`. The `<i>` tag is for "text conventionally styled in italic". There is no semantic meaning. `<em>` "represents a span of text with emphatic stress".

For more information refer the following [article](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/2013/html5-semantic-diff-bold-strong/)

Answer (score 0):

They have the same effect on normal web browser rendering engines, but there is a fundamental difference between them.

As the author writes in a discussion list post (which unfortunately isn't online anymore):

Think of three different situations:

web browsers
blind people
mobile phones

"Bold" is a style - when you say "bold a word", people basically know that it means to add more, let's say "ink" around the letters until they stand out more amongst the rest of the letters.

That, unfortunately, means nothing to a blind person. And on mobile phones and other PDAs, text is already bold because screen resolution is very small. You can't bold a bold without screwing something up.

is a style - we know what "bold" is supposed to look like.

however is an indication of how something should be understood. "Strong" could (and often does) mean "bold" in a browser, but it could also mean a lower tone for a speaking program like Jaws (for blind people). And strong on a Palm Pilot may be an underline (since you can't bold a bold).
 and  are explicit - they specify bold and italic respectively.

and  are semantic - they specify that the enclosed text should be "strong" or "emphasised" in some way, usually bold and italic, but allow for the actual styling to be controlled via CSS. Hence these are preferred in modern web pages